# @react-three / react-three-fiber: useLoader() to load new file on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a functional react component and initial load a gltf model - the path gets passed through the props - this works fine.

But if the props change the component rerenders - I checked that - the path is changed and a new Model should be loaded - but I does not.

How can one achieve this?
**I want to swap/replace the object that is rendering if the state is updated.**

I tried different loaders, set the gltf it self as a state but none of this wokred. I think I miss an underlying concept. Pls Help

```
  function Character(props) {
      const spinner = useRef();
      console.log(props.model, "from modelpreviewer");
      const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, props.model);
    
      return gltf ? (
        <primitive
          ref={spinner}
          object={gltf.scene}
        />
      ) : null;
    }
```

The Character Component is rendered like this:

```
<Canvas
   camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10] }}>
    <ambientLight intensity={0.8} />
    <spotLight intensity={0.7} position={[300, 300, 400]} />
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Character model={props.model} />
    </Suspense>
  </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I test the problem of `useLoader` when render the texture and it works fine to me.
This a simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-texture-url-forked-khr4f?file=/src/App.js) which shows the texture will change whenever the `props` changed.

I guess you're miss the correct path point to `props.model`. Maybe you can hard code a value of `props.model` to make sure the file path is correct or not.

#### Edited

I find the reason why gltf just render once. The answer is [here](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/245#issuecomment-554612085).

> You can't reuse meshes or put the same object into the scene twice in webgl/threejs, it will just unmount and remount.

An alternatively solution is to [clone the scene](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/245#issuecomment-746199895).

```
const { scene } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url)
const copiedScene = useMemo(() => scene.clone(), [scene])
```

I also provide a fixed example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-texture-url-forked-0goif?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: the path are right i tested them and there are also imported so that is not the issue.

Comment: i also modified your example to use the gltf loader and that did not work either. I dont know if it is even possible or if it has something to do with the scene

Comment: @AlexanderFrey Could you share your example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-texture-url-forked-4looe?file=/src/App.js i had to redo it it seems to worke now somehow but not 100%. maybe thats an network isue

Comment: but mine still wont work i dont know what to do

Comment: thank youu so much. i tried so many things an thought about something like this but could not get is to work! :)

Comment: dude this is such a big help in 2022. this totally solved my problems. thanks!